# Search function not doing anything

Tags: jsf, search, jpa, derby

sorry if this is a poor question but this one feature have been driving me mad for days so i thought id post it here to see if you guys can help me

basically all i want to do from a jsf page have the user search a user and for me to return all the details

```
<h:form id="searchForm">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Search: " style="font-weight:bold" />
                    <h:inputText id="search" value="#{userdetailsController.search}" />   
                    <h:commandButton value="Search" action="index"/>

                </h:form>
```

that is the jsf page, working fine

it calls my userdetailsController class

```
@Named("userdetailsController")
@SessionScoped
public class UserdetailsController implements Serializable {

    private Userdetails current;
    private DataModel items = null;
    @EJB
    private Richard.beans.UserdetailsFacade ejbFacade;
    private PaginationHelper pagination;
    private int selectedItemIndex;
    private String search;

    public String getSearch() {
        System.out.println("inGetSearch");
        return search;
    }

    public void setSearch(String search) {
        this.search = search;
    }
......
```

a contactsService class

```
@Stateless
public class ContactsService {
    // Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
    // "Insert Code > Add Business Method")

    @EJB
    private UserdetailsFacade cf;

    public List<Userdetails> searchByString(String string) {
        return cf.searchByString(string);
    }


    public List<Userdetails> getAllPersons() {
        return cf.findAll();
    }
}
```

an AbstractFacade class

```
   /* trying out a search function */
    public List<T> searchByString(String string) {
        System.out.println("in SearchByString");
        return getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Userdetails.findByUsername").setParameter("string", "%" + string + "%").getResultList();
    }
```

and the Userdetails class with the query i am trying to search

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "Userdetails.findByUsername", query = "SELECT u FROM Userdetails u WHERE u.username = :username")})
```

currently only the getters and settings are working in Getsearch

how can i make this work as i have spent days on this feature and are still no closer, sorry this is my first time at this

thanks guys

EDIT

would adding

```
public List<Userdetails> getAllPersons() {
    if (search == null) {
        return cs.getAllPersons();
    }
    return cs.searchByString(search);
}
```

in the UserdetailsController be enough ?

Comment: So far in your code, you're not performing the search of the users anywhere.

Comment: ok, how can i do that? sorry this is my first go at jpa

Comment: This is not a JPA problem. You should grab a book and start reading about basic JSF and another for JPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not invoking any action here:

```
<h:commandButton value="Search" action="index"/>
```

So it's indeed logical that it isn't "doing anything".

You need to invoke a managed bean action which in turn executes the desired code to obtain the desired data from the DB and assign to a property:

```
<h:commandButton value="Search" action="#{userdetailsController.submit}" />
```

with inside `UserdetailsController`:

```
private String search;
private List<UserDetail> items; // No need for DataModel here.
@EJB
private UserdetailsFacade ejbFacade;

public String submit() {
    items = ejbFacade.searchByString(search);
    return "index";
}
```

Your whole `ContactsService` seems useless by the way.

As per your attempt in the getter method in the update of your question, please don't do that. You should never call the DB in a getter method for the reasons mentioned in [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062)

Comment: Hi there thanks very much for the answer, it now run and everything but when i search the username `test` i get the following error message 

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a parameter value using a name of string that does not exist in the query string SELECT u FROM Userdetails u WHERE u.username = :username.`

how can this be corrected

Comment: This is unrelated to the question currently asked. Press "Ask Question" button on right top in order to be able to get an answer on that.