# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a parameter value using a name of string that does not exist in the query string

Tags: jpa, parameters, derby, named-query

I have the following named query:

```
@NamedQuery(
    name = "Userdetails.findByUsername", 
    query = "SELECT u FROM Userdetails u WHERE u.username = :username"
)
```

When I try to execute it as follows:

```
getEntityManager()
    .createNamedQuery("Userdetails.findByUsername")
    .setParameter("string", "%" + string + "%")
    .getResultList();
```

Then I get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a parameter value using a name of string that does not exist in the query string SELECT u FROM Userdetails u WHERE u.username = :username.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: That error message seems to be pretty clear. Im confused as to what assistance you're seeking. If you have a code question you'll need to post some code.

Comment: Read the error. You've probably got a placeholder `:foo` in your query, but are trying to bind a value for `:baz` or something like that.

Comment: sorry this is my first project like this and using these technologies, what is causing this error, the fields in the database are only i.d. and username, the username is what i trying to return, i just dont understand how i can fix this

Comment: The problem is in your JPA code from your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20080195/1065197. You have `:username` as named parameter but setting `string` in `return getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Userdetails.findByUsername").setParameter("string", "%" + string + "%").getResultList();`.

Comment: Thanks a lot i think it is working now, i jsut have to display the results but think i need some sleep now ! thanks guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here in your `Userdetails.findByUsername` named query you have a named parameter called `username`:

```
SELECT u FROM Userdetails u WHERE u.username = :username
```

Then you call it using the Entity Manager but set a `string` parameter:

```
getEntityManager()
    .createNamedQuery("Userdetails.findByUsername")
    .setParameter("string", "%" + string + "%") //<-- check here
    .getResultList();
```

Replace this `string` parameter by `username`:

```
getEntityManager()
    .createNamedQuery("Userdetails.findByUsername")
    .setParameter("username", "%" + string + "%") //<-- check here
    .getResultList();
```